# Best practice to setup tsconfig "files" vs "include"?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I was wondering what is better and what are the pros and cons of using "files" vs "include" in tsconfig?

I don't really like the include pattern because is just including all ts files in the src folder, and I might now want that.

I like the "files" approach, because I can point to the entry file and just load everything that file needs.

I'm using typescript with webpack. I guess the entry point is defined in webpack so there is no need to define in typescript as well?

I tried to use "files" but looks like there is no way to set a folder to look for custom type definitions: [typescript with tsconfig with "files" => import image module not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51798600/typescript-with-tsconfig-with-files-import-image-module-not-found?noredirect=1#comment90566928_51798600)

Answer (score 35):

There are [two examples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#examples) of `tsconfig.json` presented on the official website of TypeScript,—one with `"files"` property, another one with `"include"` and `"exclude"` properties specified:

> #### Using the `"files"` property
>
> ```
> {
>     "compilerOptions": {
>         // irrelevant
>     },
>     "files": [
>         "core.ts",
>         "sys.ts",
>         "types.ts",
>         "scanner.ts",
>         "parser.ts",
>         "utilities.ts",
>         "binder.ts",
>         "checker.ts",
>         "emitter.ts",
>         "program.ts",
>         "commandLineParser.ts",
>         "tsc.ts",
>         "diagnosticInformationMap.generated.ts"
>     ]
> }
> ```
>
> #### Using the `"include"` and `"exclude"` properties
>
> ```
> {
>     "compilerOptions": {
>         // irrelevant
>     },
>     "include": [
>         "src/**/*"
>     ],
>     "exclude": [
>         "node_modules",
>         "**/*.spec.ts"
>     ]
> }
> ```

So, basically, `"files"` is used to specify separate files directly by their path, while `"include"` and `"exclude"` is used to target collections or groups of files or folders etc.

Comment: Can both be used at the same time?

Comment: @Marek: yes – and stuff in "files" will never be ruled out by "exclude" patterns, if you add any, whereas stuff from "include" will. (If you add just a "files" array and expect all else you had before to stay as it was, also add the default rule `"include": ["**/*"]` that you got for free when you had no "files" rule.)

Answer (score 0):

There are some interesting considerations and examples about that in the documentation: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#root-fields).
Basically the `"files"` is used if there isn't a large amount of file to be included.