# Typescript is type-checking not included files?

Tags: typescript

I think this has to do with the "include" instead of "files" in tsconfig. [Best practice to setup tsconfig "files" vs "include"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51819184/best-practice-to-setup-tsconfig-files-vs-include)

"typescript": "^2.8.3"

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "traceResolution": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "allowUnreachableCode": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts",
    "src/server",
    "config",
    "buildServer"
  ]
}
```

webpack.modules.rules:

```
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        include: paths.appSrc,
        use: [
          {
            loader: require.resolve('ts-loader'),
            options: {
              // disable type checker - we will use it in fork plugin
              transpileOnly: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

webpack.plugins:

```
new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
  async: false,
  watch: paths.appSrc,
  tsconfig: paths.appTsConfig,
}),
```

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: Sorry is not clear. I don't want typescript to include all files, just the ones imported by the index file.

Comment: include to the bundle? that fully depends on webpack. typechecking should happen with regards to "exclude" option in tsconfig. doesn't work?

Comment: Is not including the file, is just type-checking it. The file is not in the bundle. If I put a typescript error in that file will break the build, even if that file is not used. I don't want to exclude, because I might have many spare files not used in that particular bundle. I just want all the files that are imported by the entry file

Comment: This problem is driving me up the wall. Did you ever find a solution?